# Can I pass column names in this manner?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

```
query = "UPDATE personal_details SET '" + field + "' = '" + edit + "' WHERE associate_id = '" + associate_id + "'";
```

Here my table name is `personal_details` and I am taking the table column name as a parameter in the variable filed and its new value in edit. This code is in Java. and the database I'm accessing is in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You could do this, and it would work, but you would be wide open to SQL injection attacks, assuming those variables are coming from user input

Comment: Yes you can pass the query like this. Are you facing any issues with this?

Comment: yes.. i removed the single quote.
query = "UPDATE personal_details SET " + field + " = '" + edit + "' WHERE associate_id = '" + associate_id + "'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can build string using plain concatenation, the more recommended ways are:

1. Use StringBuilder/StringBuffer when you build strings to optimize program speed, specially if you concatenate strings inside loop;
2. The most recommended way is to use PreparedStatement and fill parameter values. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Using StringBuilder is NOT recommended for query construction. StringBuffer is deprecated and should not be used at all anymore.

Comment: @adriaan-koster, agreed with deprecated StringBuffer, also agreed with your point that StringBuilder is not the most suitable solution. I just showed most of possible ways. Personally **me** prefer to use **PreparedStatements**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't construct queries like this! It is bad practice due to security issues, as @Rory pointed out. Instead use a PreparedStatement with parameters, for example:

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "mkyong_new_value");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1001);
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

(Taken from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/))

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a string that contains the query.  The database has no idea how the string is being constructed.  Eventually, you'll just pass the string where it will be parsed, compiled, and executed.  So yes, you can construct the query this way.

You cannot pass column names or table names as parameters into a query.  It is recommended that you pass other values as parameters into the query.